# PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI issue

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have problem with PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI in my windows Phone 8.1 universal app. When I make this call the phone call UI appears for a moment and then entire app disappears.

It works fine in debugger. I do specify valid phone number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much informations, but the problem should be of the suspension manager, while you are in debug mode the app never enter in suspension mode, instead when you run the app normally and you bring up the phone call UI the app enter in suspension and crash, the problem should be the fact that you pass an object to the view, only strings and serializable element are allowed to be passed from a view to another as parameter without having issue on the suspension manager.

Comment: I do not pass any object. I call this method in button click handler.

Comment: i mean in general not only related to this specific view, can you post some code?

Comment: Seeing the code would help, but I agree that one option is that your suspension code has a crashing bug.